# Executable not running over RDP

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interop, com-interop, hid

I have an executable written in C#. It is a simple console application, just listens for HID device events.

Here is the befuddling problem: When I start the executable when I am working on the computer physically then it works just fine, but when I am logged into the computer through RDP crashes with the following error:

[image]

I use DLLs provided by the manufacturer of the HID device

Comment: It says unknown error. that's not much to go on....It might be permissions related

Comment: Check the event log.  There may be more info there.

Comment: @EricJ. nope, no more information than the console itself :(

Comment: @MitchWheat yes, it might be permission based, but I dont know how to deal with it!

Comment: How are you selecting the device? It might be finding and choking on devices handled by the RDP server.

Comment: I am using an COM Interop DLL... this seems to be trouble and I dont have any access to the SDK source code! is there any way?